# Issues with tenants in AS 5.0.0

Tags: multi-tenant, wso2

if I´m login into tenant1 and try to consume a service of tenant2 I see this error.

```
[2012-10-20 22:39:29,050] @tenant2 [1] [Application Server]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.base.CarbonContextHolderBase} -  Trying to set the domain from tenant1 to tenant2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set the domain from tenant1 to tenant2
        at org.wso2.carbon.base.CarbonContextHolderBase.setTenantDomain(CarbonContextHolderBase.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.CarbonContextHolder.setTenantDomain(CarbonContextHolder.java:633)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.SuperTenantCarbonContext.setTenantDomain(SuperTenantCarbonContext.java:228)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doSOAP(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterServletAdaptor.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.jsservices.custom.ui.CustomUIServletFilter.doFilter(CustomUIServletFilter.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor.service(FilterServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

[2012-10-20 22:39:29,058] @tenant2 [1] [Application Server]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.base.CarbonContextHolderBase} -  Trying to set the domain from 2
 to 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set the domain from 2 to 1
        at org.wso2.carbon.base.CarbonContextHolderBase.setTenantId(CarbonContextHolderBase.java:214)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.CarbonContextHolder.setTenantId(CarbonContextHolder.java:595)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.SuperTenantCarbonContext.setTenantId(SuperTenantCarbonContext.java:193)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.SuperTenantCarbonContext.setTenantId(SuperTenantCarbonContext.java:182)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.SuperTenantCarbonContext.resolveTenantId(SuperTenantCarbonContext.java:296)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.SuperTenantCarbonContext.setTenantDomain(SuperTenantCarbonContext.java:232)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doSOAP(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterServletAdaptor.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.jsservices.custom.ui.CustomUIServletFilter.doFilter(CustomUIServletFilter.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor.service(FilterServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

another concern related to multitenancy is the fact that I can see the messages send and receive in a particular tenant from the supertenant. this is not a security issue?? that is not happen with all tenants, it seem like a random error or just with the first service tenant that I call.

Answer (score 0):

This was a minor bug and has been resolved. It occurs only when you are using TryIt with the valid browser session.

The fix will be available with the next minor release.